# How to validate username and password

Tags: javascript, html, json

I am using a flat JSON file as my database and I want to validate a username and password from my JSON file to access a certain HTML site through JavaScript. My JSON data looks like this:

```
"1": {
    "username": "Chris1",
    "firstname": "Martin",
    "lastname": "Johnson",
    "age": "30",
    "gender": "Male",
    "interest": "Football",
    "password1": "123456"
  }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So you basically want to parse a JSON file and read its data?

Comment: Yes. I want to validate if the username and password match with the user input on my log in page in HTML

Comment: Do you mean you want to load and validate the json data from the front-end application itself? You should never do that. If the application can loads the .json file, anyone will can too.

Comment: Yes exactly. I know it may sound silly, but it is for a school project, so it does not matter for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can parse data from a JSON file like so:

```
    var Jsonfile = yourJSONfileAsString;
    var obj = JSON.parse(Jsonfile);
    obj.attribute; //access the elemets you want as attributes of the object
```

I assume you already have the JSON file available for your code to process. If not, then a method to get the JSON file to your front-end JavaScript code is to make an Http request using the [XMLHttpRequest](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp).